How to set up Github CI/CD pipeline with Real IP?
I have .net 6 API. I want to set automatic deployment using Github actions. I want to set up CD with SSH so that after pushing to the branch it will be deployed to my server using the SSH key and real IP.
I tried the below:
name: Build and Deploy API

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production  # Trigger pipeline on push to production branch

jobs:
 deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build_publish_api

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Download API artifacts
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: api-artifacts

    - name: Deploy API to server
      env:
         SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      run: |
         echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > key.pem
         chmod 600 key.pem
         scp -i key.pem -P 1322 -r ./build/API/ username@real-ip:/C/inetpub/wwwroot/BRPPIMS/API

Here 1322 is the external port which is forwarded.
I get the error:

ssh: connect to host 119.xx.xx.xx port 1322: Connection timed out
lost connection


Do you need to use SCP instead of FTP? In any case, you WILL have to create an app_offline.htm file and add a 5s delay. Here's an example

This looks like a https://devops.stackexchange.com/ question.

Any specific reason to use windows? When the artifact is already prepared?

@Pieterjan what  app_offline.htm file will do?

@avifen, there is no specific reason.

So I think it will be cheaper and easier to work with Ubuntu latest.

Edited my answer

The asp.net core application locks your dll's and exe's, which prevents the ftp/scp/... deployment from deleting/overwriting them. By creating an app_offline.htm the app will shutdown nearly immediately, and release these files. But you have to also wait 5s after creating the app_offline.htm, just to be sure (eg by doing ping -n 5 127.0.0.1)

You can replace the writing to key.pem and increase timeout by doing as below + work with Linux, life is better if you do so + you can check out 4 + add shell:
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Download API artifacts
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: api-artifacts

    - name: Set up SSH
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.9.0
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: Deploy API to server
      shell: bash
      run: |
        scp -o ConnectTimeout=60 -P 1322 -r ./build/API/ username@real-ip:/C/inetpub/wwwroot/BRPPIMS/API

You can eliminate some optional issues.
If this is not helping, you should debug a bit more verbosely:
add -v e.g., scp -v ...
Check ssh access itself —
- name: Check SSH access
  run: |
    ssh -vvv -i key.pem -p 1322 username@real-ip echo "SSH has access"

Try with 22 to check it is not the port.
Check for general connectivity issues:
- name: Check another IP address
  run: curl https://ifconfig.me

To your server:
- name: Ping your server
  run: |
    ping -c 4 real-ip || echo "Ping failed, your server unreachable"

If some of those fail, there are other steps to continue to mitigate, so let me know.
